Query on Microsoft Intune SDK Integration with Flutter App
I am currently developing an app using Flutter that requires integration with Microsoft Intune for Mobile Application Management (MAM) and security policies. I have reviewed available resources but need clarification on the following:
Intune SDK Compatibility: Does the Microsoft Intune SDK support direct integration with Flutter apps? Most Intune documentation seems focused on native iOS and Android apps, and I’d like to confirm if Flutter can support these MAM policies without major modifications.
Platform-Specific Code: Would I need to implement platform-specific native code (iOS/Android) to properly integrate the Intune SDK with Flutter? If so, are there best practices for handling this integration, particularly with Flutter’s method channels or platform code?
Intune App Wrapping Tool: Is there any official support or guidance for using the Intune App Wrapping Tool with a Flutter-built app? Since the tool is designed for native applications, I would appreciate any advice on how it could be applied in the context of a Flutter project.
Our goal is to meet enterprise security and compliance standards using Microsoft Intune while maintaining the flexibility of our Flutter setup. Any insights, best practices, or recommended approaches for achieving this integration would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your support!
What did I try?
We have reviewed the official Microsoft Intune documentation, but it primarily covers integration with native iOS and Android apps.
We explored using platform-specific code in Flutter for iOS and Android, but are uncertain about the compatibility and the right approach to integrate the Intune SDK.
Investigated whether Intune’s App Wrapping Tool can be applied to our Flutter project, but found limited information about its use with Flutter or cross-platform frameworks.
What I'm expecting?
I was expecting to find clear guidelines or support for integrating the Intune SDK directly with Flutter, or documentation on how to apply Intune policies and MAM functionality in a Flutter environment.
I was also hoping to understand whether it's possible to use the Intune App Wrapping Tool with a Flutter-built app, or if there are any recommended alternative approaches for integrating Intune’s capabilities into Flutter applications.

We have managed to include Microsoft Intune MAM support in to our flutter app. Currently having million of users, some of our customers wanted to manage the app from intune.
When accompanied with the company portal app on the device, we've shipped a version in the play and apple store with MAM intune policies enforced. We used the Android aar and the IOS framework. No need for MSAL was needed, as we did not know the MSAL clientid at compile time.
Flutter 3.24.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Android: Added the aar file and used the gradle script provided by Microsoft to handle all the class renames. Used the MAMComponents for a channel call from flutter to check on policies and user entraid.
IOS: Added the MAM swift frameworks and msal framework. Used AutoEnrollOnLaunch to enroll the known entra id from company portal.
